# Latex convert Date string format from mm/dd/yyyyy to dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: date

I want to change date format for date string

Ex. /changeformat{'06/23/2016'} and result = 23 June 2016

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\changeformat#1{\xchangeformat#1\relax}
\def\xchangeformat#1/#2/#3\relax{%
#2 %
\ifcase#1 \or
January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or July\or
August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
\ #3}

\begin{document}

\changeformat{06/23/2016} and result = 23 June 2016

\end{document}
```

Comment: After I've tried it was display [July] instead of [June]
After check It seems that it haven't [April]

Comment: @user3863074 oops, fixed:-)

Answer (score 4):

This solution uses `datetime2`, so you can apply the official format for a given country, or any format you choose, with day of week.

Also, it works with any seperator of your choice, so if you can use `06/23/2016` ,`06.23.2016` or whatever you throw at it.

The format-changing is done with `xstring`.

**Output**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass[11pt, australian]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage[useregional, calc]{datetime2}
\newcommand{\changeformat}[1]{%
    \StrRight{#1}{4}[\myyear]%
    \StrLeft{#1}{2}[\mymonth]%
    \StrMid{#1}{4}{5}[\mydate]%
    \DTMdate{\myyear-\mymonth-\mydate}%
    }

\DTMusemodule{british}{en-GB} % Only neaded for extra languages.
\begin{document}

\changeformat{06/23/2016}

\DTMsetdatestyle{iso}
\changeformat{06/23/2016}

\DTMsetdatestyle{ddmmyyyy}
\changeformat{06.23.2016}


\DTMlangsetup[en-GB]{abbr}
\DTMsetstyle{en-GB}
\DTMsetup{showdow}
\changeformat{06/23/2016}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\renewcommand*\today{\number\day\space
  \ifcase\month\or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi\space
  \number\year}

\begin{document}

\today

\end{document}
```