# Convert Date string format from dd-mm-yyyy to dd.mm.yyyy with some feature

Tags: strings, def

I need to convert a date from one format to another. This is a very simple problem that has already been solved in the topic [Latex convert Date string format from mm/dd/yyyyy to dd/MM/yyyy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316253/latex-convert-date-string-format-from-mm-dd-yyyyy-to-dd-mm-yyyy). However, there is a peculiarity in my case. The date is determined through `\def\date#1{\def\thedate{#1}}` and in this case the error `Paragraph ended before \todots was complete` occurs:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\date#1{\def\thedate{#1}}
\def\datetodots#1{\todots#1\relax}
\def\todots#1-#2-#3\relax{#1.#2.#3}

\begin{document}

\date{3-10-2023}

\thedate

\datetodots{\thedate}

\end{document}
```

This is a minimal example, but it is part of a huge class in which the editor, in different commands defines different dates for processing the article and, via different variants of `\def\date#1{\def\thedate{#1}}` macro, defines several dates that need to be displayed and save to a file in different formats. Is it possible to solve the problem without using `xstring` and LaTeX3? I will be grateful to the community for help and tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to expand the argument before calling `\todots`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\date#1{\def\thedate{#1}}
\def\datetodots#1{\expandafter\todots\expanded{#1}\relax}
\def\todots#1-#2-#3\relax{#1.#2.#3}

\begin{document}

\date{3-10-2023}

\thedate

\datetodots{\thedate}

\datetodots{3-10-2023}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly! Thank you!